# Setting default font/face

Tags: fonts

I'm using Emacs nightly, and I suspect some font code has changed, or maybe it's just how I've been using it doesn't work anymore.

I do something like this:

```el
(defun find-font-size (name size &optional frame)
  "Find font named NAME of size SIZE"
  (let* ((font (or (find-font (font-spec :family name
                                         :slant 'normal
                                         :weight 'medium
                                         :size size)
                              frame)
                   (find-font (font-spec :family name
                                         :slant 'normal
                                         :weight 'normal
                                         :size size)
                              frame)))
         )
    font
    ))
```

to get a font of a given name and size. In my latest emacs, that returns a font entity with the right family, but height of 0. When I then try to set that using `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font font)` it doesn't change my font to the desired size.

I see that `(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family NAME :height (* (round size) 10))` works OK, but I'd like to test my list of fonts (I use different machines with different fonts installed sometimes) and use the "best" one that exists, so that's why I've been using my `get-font-size` code and using the returned font.

My question is why does `(find-font)` return a font without a height, even if I pass in a valid size?

My secondary question is the doc suggests not using the ["low-level" font functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Font.html), but sticking instead to the face functions. Can I test for existence of a font like my code above without using those low-level functions?

Comment: BTW, I don't use `face-font-family-alternatives` because different fonts look best at different sizes. So I go through my list of `(font-name . size)` to find the best one and use that.

Comment: Emacs doesn't have a "nightly" release, and there are multiple branches under development.  Tell us which version you're actually using.

Comment: If you think there's a bug (including absent documentation of a feature change) then `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Sorry, nightly based on master of 2 days ago, commit 8716f21d94. Linux/Ubuntu-20.04.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or just me not understanding how the low-level font code works (only been using Emacs for 35 years, so I'm still learning, haha). Hence my posting here before submitting a bug report. Don't want to bother the devs unless it's a real issue.

Comment: I have no knowledge of what's supposed to happen with that font code, but you can definitely expect to encounter bugs on the `master` branch.  I suggest that you compare with Emacs 28, and if the problem doesn't exist there or if you can't see any new documentation describing the change, then it would be reasonable to report a bug.  I would check both the NEWS and the in-built manual.